# Google Play Game Services VS Google Drive

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-drive-api

I want to add a user data backup service to my Android app. I found two options for this through searching. One is **Cloud Save** from **Google Play Game Services**, and the other is **Google Drive**. I checked a google account for my phone and found out some android games, such as **Tab Titans** are using Google Drive for saving data.

I'm using Unity3D now, even though what I'm developing is not a game but just a simple utility. And I also have a plan to use Multiplayer feature from Google Play Game Services very soon. So, I think **GPGS** seems to fit for me, but wonder if there are any limits or cons when using it on the app which is not a game.

I don't know what are the differences between using Google Play Game Services and Google Drive for saving user data at all, so I googled for hours but couldn't find any.

The user data would be a SQLite db and some more.

**Can I use Google Play Game Services to back up such files?**

If possible, could anyone explain the differences between those two services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play Services is like a suite of Google products and services packaged altogether. Though Google Drive may be part of Google Play Services, it's better to think of them separately. If this is on Unity, then I second using Google Play Services, especially, the [plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity). With it, you should be able to easily implement [Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames), at least significantly easier than making Drive calls, as there's no plugin (that I know of) for Unity to interface with Google Drive. This highly depends on what kind of data you want to store, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! About the plugin, I think it doesn't that matter. I haven't tried yet, but I can deal with it creating some jar files of my own for Unity3d. But I didn't know there's no plugin for Google Drive yet and agree it would be much easier with GPGS, thanks!